# injecting groups through a source block using probabilities

Tags: anylogic

So, the problem i'm facing is the following:

In a student cafeteria, students arrive every 30 seconds in group sizes of 1, 2, 3 or 4. The probabilities for the 4 groups sizes are 50% , 20% , 5% and 25% respectively.

How can I make sure that my source block can achieve this sort of injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleaner way to do this is using custom distributions like this:

[image: custom distribution]

and then you only need one line of code:

```
mySource.inject(customDistribution());
```

Answer (score 2):

Benjamin's method for randomly choosing how many to inject will give you wrong probabilities for your group sizes. To see why this is, consider the probability of getting a group of 2 with Benjamin's method.

To get a group of 2 with Benjamin's method, the first if statement: `if(randomTrue(0.5)` must be false **and** the second condition: `else if(randomTrue(0.2)` must also be true. This occurs with a probability of 0.1, giving roughly 10% of the groups a size of 2 rather than 20%.

I tested this out with 100,000 samples and with Benjamin's method, the following results were seen:
[image: Sample using randomTrue]

The frequencies of group sizes are not matching up with what you wanted!
To properly assign group sizes, use the following method instead:

```
double u = uniform(0,1);

if(u < 0.5)
{
    mySource.inject(1);
}
else if(u < 0.7)
{
    mySource.inject(2);
}
else if(u < 0.75)
{
    mySource.inject(3);
}
else
{
    mySource.inject(4);
}
```

I ran the same test with 100,000 samples using this method, and the following results were seen:
[image: Results using uniform]

Looking much better. Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Yep, that's the solution that gives the desired output. If this is placed in a cyclical event, I also want to point at that self.restart(); should be put at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the Source block to be used "on calls of 'inject()' method":
[image]

Now create a cyclic event (every 30 sec or whatever you need). In it, create as many agents in the source as prescribed by your probabilities, something like:

```
if (randomTrue(0.5)) {
    mySource.inject(1);
} else if (randomTrue(0.2)) {
    mySource.inject(2);
} else...
```

Comment: In hinsight I see that the solution only works well for two cases (only an if and an else) as the parameter p returns true and 1 - p returns false.